# Can't lock screen through unity

Tags: unity, 14.04, lock-screen, gnome-screensaver

I can't lock my screen through keyboard shortcut or dropdown menu.

Here's the twist - I **CAN** lock it by running gnome-screensaver-command -l in a terminal.

How do I diagnose this?